# Attribute error when trying to batch send events to an Event Hub

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I'm getting the below error when running my Azure function which I want to batch send events that it pulls from blobs.

> Result: Failure Exception: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'header' Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.11/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 491, in _handle__invocation_request call_result = await self._run_async_func( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.11/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 774, in _run_async_func return await ExtensionManager.get_async_invocation_wrapper( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.11/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/extension.py", line 147, in get_async_invocation_wrapper result = await function(**args) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/home/site/wwwroot/AzureFunctionCloudflare/main-edited.py", line 83, in main await asyncio.gather(*cors) File "/home/site/wwwroot/AzureFunctionCloudflare/main-edited.py", line 189, in process_blob await event_data_batch.add([EventData(json.dumps(event))]) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/eventhub/_common.py", line 685, in add outgoing_event_data = transform_outbound_single_message( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/eventhub/_utils.py", line 261, in transform_outbound_single_message amqp_message = to_outgoing_amqp_message(message) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/eventhub/_transport/_pyamqp_transport.py", line 99, in to_outgoing_amqp_message header_vals = annotated_message.header.values() if annotated_message.header else None ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

The data in the blobs is multiple single lines of JSON i.e.

```json
{"QueryName":"domain1.co.uk.","QueryType":2,"ResponseCode":0,"Timestamp":"2023-10-24T15:28:50Z","SourceIP":"x.x.x.x"}
{"QueryName":"domain2.co.uk.","QueryType":2,"ResponseCode":0,"Timestamp":"2023-10-24T15:28:50Z","SourceIP":"x.x.x.x"}
{"QueryName":"domain3.co.uk.","QueryType":2,"ResponseCode":0,"Timestamp":"2023-10-24T15:28:50Z","SourceIP":"x.x.x.x"}
```

This is based off the function here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/data-connectors/cloudflare-using-azure-functions

This is the function I am using to process the blobs:

```py
async def process_blob(self, blob, container_client, session: aiohttp.ClientSession):
        
    async with self.semaphore:
        logging.info("Start processing {}".format(blob['name']))
        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob['name'])
        tags = await blob_client.get_blob_tags()
        updated_tags = {'StartedProcessing': 'true'}
        tags.update(updated_tags)
        await blob_client.set_blob_tags(tags)
    
        # Create a producer client to send messages to the Event Hub
        connection_str = 'removed'
        event_hub_producer = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(connection_str, eventhub_name='cloudflare')
    
        blob_cor = await container_client.download_blob(blob['name'])
        s = ''
    
        async with event_hub_producer:
    
            # Create a Batch
            event_data_batch = await event_hub_producer.create_batch()
    
            # Process blob chunks
            async for chunk in blob_cor.chunks():
                s += chunk.decode()
                lines = re.split(r'{0}'.format(LINE_SEPARATOR), s)
                lines = self.merge_lines(data=lines)
                for n, line in enumerate(lines):
                    if n < len(lines) - 1:
                        if line:
                            try:
                                event = json.loads(line)
                                await event_data_batch.add([EventData(json.dumps(event))])
                            except JSONDecodeError as je:
                                logging.error(
                                    'JSONDecode error while loading json event at line value {}. blob name: {}. Error {}'.format(
                                        line, blob['name'], str(je)))
                            except ValueError as e:
                                logging.error(
                                    'Error while loading json Event at line value {}. blob name: {}. Error: {}'.format(
                                        line, blob['name'], str(e)))
                                raise e
                    s = line
            if s:
                try:
                    event = json.loads(s)
                except JSONDecodeError as je:
                    logging.error(
                        'JSONDecode error while loading json event at line value {}. blob name: {}. Error {}'.format(
                            line, blob['name'], str(je)))
                except ValueError as e:
                    logging.error('Error while loading json Event at s value {}. blob name: {}. Error: {}'.format(
                        line, blob['name'], str(e)))
                    raise e
                await event_data_batch.add([EventData(json.dumps(event))])
    
            # Send the batch of Events
            await event_hub_producer.send_batch(event_data_batch)
    
            # Delete the Blob
            await self.delete_blob(blob, container_client)
            self.total_blobs += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me for both single message and a batch.

I have created a `Blobtrigger` to get file data from uploaded files. and used `Eventhubtrigger` to confirm the data is being sent to event hub and used your json data for batch.

**My Code:**

**`BlobTrigger1/__init__.py`:**

```py
import logging
import json
from azure.functions import InputStream


def main(myblob: InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    content= myblob.read().decode('utf-8')
    logging.info(f"Content: {content}")
    return content
```

**`BlobTrigger1/function.json`:**

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "test/{name}",
      "connection": "c8d044_STORAGE"
    },
    {
      "type": "eventHub",
      "name": "$return",
      "eventHubName": "test_eventhub",
      "connection": "MyEventHubSendAppSetting",
      "direction": "out"
  }
  ]
}
```

**`EventHubTriger1/__init__.py`:**

```py
import logging

from azure.functions import EventHubEvent
from typing import List


def main(events: List[EventHubEvent]):
    for event in events:
        logging.info('Python EventHub trigger processed an event: %s',
                      event.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

**`EventHubTriger1/function.json`:**

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "events",
      "direction": "in",
      "eventHubName": "test_eventhub",
      "connection": "MyEventHubSendAppSetting",
      "cardinality": "many",
      "consumerGroup": "$Default"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Single message
**`test1.json`:**

```json
{
  "FirstName": "Vivek",
  "LastName": "Shandilya",
  "Platform": "stackoverflow"
}
```

**Batch**
**`test2.json`:**

```json
[
{"QueryName":"domain1.co.uk.","QueryType":2,"ResponseCode":0,"Timestamp":"2023-10-24T15:28:50Z","SourceIP":"x.x.x.x"},
{"QueryName":"domain2.co.uk.","QueryType":2,"ResponseCode":0,"Timestamp":"2023-10-24T15:28:50Z","SourceIP":"x.x.x.x"},
{"QueryName":"domain3.co.uk.","QueryType":2,"ResponseCode":0,"Timestamp":"2023-10-24T15:28:50Z","SourceIP":"x.x.x.x"}
]
```

**`OUTPUT`:**

**Single Message**

```markdown
Functions:

        BlobTrigger1: blobTrigger

        EventHubTrigger1: eventHubTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-02-02T05:02:42.381Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000AAE5F384'.
[2024-02-02T05:03:02.396Z] Executing 'Functions.BlobTrigger1' (Reason='New blob detected(LogsAndContainerScan): test/accepted.json', Id=d8c03f54-945f-472a-bf03-d4b989eaf19e)
[2024-02-02T05:03:02.399Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: 352f7309-e4d8-428f-8196-d5ea953f4049, DequeueCount: 1, InsertedOn: 2024-02-02T05:03:02.000+00:00, BlobCreated: 2024-02-02T05:03:00.000+00:00, BlobLastModified: 2024-02-02T05:03:00.000+00:00
[2024-02-02T05:03:02.510Z] Content: {
[2024-02-02T05:03:02.510Z] Python blob trigger function processed blob
Name: test/accepted.json
Blob Size: None bytes
[2024-02-02T05:03:02.512Z]   "FirstName": "Vivek",
[2024-02-02T05:03:02.515Z]   "LastName": "Shandilya",
[2024-02-02T05:03:02.517Z]   "Platform": "stackoverflow"
[2024-02-02T05:03:02.522Z] }
[2024-02-02T05:03:04.877Z] Executed 'Functions.BlobTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=d8c03f54-945f-472a-bf03-d4b989eaf19e, Duration=2591ms)
[2024-02-02T05:03:04.915Z] Executing 'Functions.EventHubTrigger1' (Reason='(null)', Id=9a6eb9a0-9874-4221-a8d5-3550a87591be)
[2024-02-02T05:03:04.917Z] Trigger Details: PartionId: 0, Offset: 1904-1904, EnqueueTimeUtc: 2024-02-02T05:03:04.1300000+00:00-2024-02-02T05:03:04.1300000+00:00, SequenceNumber: 12-12, Count: 1
[2024-02-02T05:03:04.999Z] Python EventHub trigger processed an event: {"FirstName": "Vivek", "LastName": "Shandilya", "Platform": "stackoverflow"}
[2024-02-02T05:03:05.002Z] Executed 'Functions.EventHubTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=9a6eb9a0-9874-4221-a8d5-3550a87591be, Duration=105ms)
```

[image]

**Batch**

```
Functions:

        BlobTrigger1: blobTrigger

        EventHubTrigger1: eventHubTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-02-02T05:06:20.626Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000AAE5F384'.
[2024-02-02T05:06:28.479Z] Executing 'Functions.BlobTrigger1' (Reason='New blob detected(LogsAndContainerScan): test/Query.json', Id=9093c82f-8a4d-4043-891f-427ee31563d3)
[2024-02-02T05:06:28.484Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: e3b06c44-3022-40bc-8155-a57d324f56af, DequeueCount: 1, InsertedOn: 2024-02-02T05:06:28.000+00:00, BlobCreated: 2024-02-02T05:06:27.000+00:00, BlobLastModified: 2024-02-02T05:06:27.000+00:00
[2024-02-02T05:06:28.602Z] Content: [
[2024-02-02T05:06:28.605Z] {"QueryName":"domain1.co.uk.","QueryType":2,"ResponseCode":0,"Timestamp":"2023-10-24T15:28:50Z","SourceIP":"x.x.x.x"}, 
[2024-02-02T05:06:28.602Z] Python blob trigger function processed blob
Name: test/Query.json
Blob Size: None bytes
[2024-02-02T05:06:28.607Z] {"QueryName":"domain2.co.uk.","QueryType":2,"ResponseCode":0,"Timestamp":"2023-10-24T15:28:50Z","SourceIP":"x.x.x.x"}, 
[2024-02-02T05:06:28.610Z] {"QueryName":"domain3.co.uk.","QueryType":2,"ResponseCode":0,"Timestamp":"2023-10-24T15:28:50Z","SourceIP":"x.x.x.x"}  
[2024-02-02T05:06:28.611Z] ]
[2024-02-02T05:06:30.488Z] Executed 'Functions.BlobTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=9093c82f-8a4d-4043-891f-427ee31563d3, Duration=2078ms)
[2024-02-02T05:06:30.612Z] Executing 'Functions.EventHubTrigger1' (Reason='(null)', Id=8a3afed7-ae38-4622-a036-7b13ae9165f9)
[2024-02-02T05:06:30.614Z] Trigger Details: PartionId: 0, Offset: 2648-3048, EnqueueTimeUtc: 2024-02-02T05:06:29.8860000+00:00-2024-02-02T05:06:29.8860000+00:00, SequenceNumber: 16-18, Count: 3
[2024-02-02T05:06:30.681Z] Python EventHub trigger processed an event: {"QueryName": "domain1.co.uk.", "QueryType": 2, "ResponseCode": 0, "Timestamp": "2023-10-24T15:28:50Z", "SourceIP": "x.x.x.x"}[2024-02-02T05:06:30.681Z] Python EventHub trigger processed an event: {"QueryName": "domain2.co.uk.", "QueryType": 2, "ResponseCode": 0, "Timestamp": "2023-10-24T15:28:50Z", "SourceIP": "x.x.x.x"}

[2024-02-02T05:06:30.682Z] Python EventHub trigger processed an event: {"QueryName": "domain3.co.uk.", "QueryType": 2, "ResponseCode": 0, "Timestamp": "2023-10-24T15:28:50Z", "SourceIP": "x.x.x.x"}
[2024-02-02T05:06:30.685Z] Executed 'Functions.EventHubTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=8a3afed7-ae38-4622-a036-7b13ae9165f9, Duration=107ms)
```

[image]